# Play2 calling multiple webservices with AsyncResult (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, promise

I have a Play 2.1 controller in Java, and I need to call an external webservice to get some data. Then with this data result, I must call another web service with n calls, corresponding to the n results from the first webservice call.

For performance issues, I want to make the n calls in separated threads using promises.

So I would have a loop like this:

```
List<String> firstResults = WS.url("http://...") ///...blablabla

for(String keyword : firstResults){
  Promise<ResultType> promise = play.libs.Akka.future(
    new Callable<ResultType>() {
      public Integer call() {
        return //...
      }
    }
  );}
```

How can I synchronize the n promises and then reduce the results in one response (a list of all results) using the Async API, and then return the http responses only when all calls are finished?

Not being able to know the number of calls make the problem more difficult ... (I can't declare promises as promise1, promise2 etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Promise.waitAll is what you want:

```
List<String> firstResults = WS.url("http://...") ///...blablabla

List<Promise<? extends ResultType>> webServiceCalls = new ArrayList<>;
for(String keyword : firstResults){
  Promise<ResultType> promise = WS.url("http://...?keyboard=" + keyword).get().map(
    // function of Response to ResultType
  );
  webServiceCalls.add(promise);
}

// Don't be confused by the name here, it's not actually waiting
Promise<List<ResultType>> results = Promise.waitAll(webServiceCalls);

return async(results.map(new Function<List<ResultType, Result>>() {
  public Result apply(List<ResultType> results) {
    // Convert results to ResultType
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks James, this is exactly what I needed!

What would be the equivalent of "waitAll" in the Scala Iteratee API?

Comment: waitAll confusing name has been resolved, now the method is named "sequence" :)

Comment: Since iteratees are consumers that produce a result from what they've consumed, not future values, it doesn't really make sense to waitAll or sequence on a number of iteratees.  But you can, for example, use Enumeratee.zip or Enumeratee.zipWith, to have two iteratees consume the same stream, and produce a tuple of their results.